# Creating dynamic buttons with for loop issue (Android, JAVA)

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am trying to create code that creates differnet media player buttons dynamically depending on the amount of wav files created in a seperate android studio activty.

Each wav file is saved with the following file path

```
/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/event1.wav

/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/event2.wav

/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/event3.wav
```

This is the code that creates the buttons and puts them in an array:

```
   Button[] buttonsPlay = new Button[data];


    for (int loop = 0; loop < data ; loop++) {
        playID ++;

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(playID);
        button.setText("Play event "+playID);
        String buttonName = "PlayEvent" + playID;
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 50));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
        ll.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        button.setLayoutParams(ll);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        buttonsPlay[loop] = button;
    }
```

Once each button is created I want to loop through all the buttons in the array and play the corresponding wav file.

This is my attempt so far

```
        playID = 0;

  for (int loop = 0 ; loop < buttonsPlay.length ; loop ++){
        playID++;


        Toast.makeText(  ctx, "play is " +  playID , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        buttonsPlay[loop] = (Button) findViewById(  buttonsPlay[loop].getId());
        buttonsPlay[loop].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String dataSource = "/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/event"+ playID +".wav";


                playEvent( dataSource);


            }

        });
```

Unfortunately every time I play the wav it only plays the last wav event created.

For example if there where 10 wav files, every button pressed plays:

"/data/data/com.example.androidaudiorecorder/files/event10.wav"

If anyone has any advice about how to correct this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm curious what the contents of `playEvent(String dataSource)` is. However, I would highly recommend replacing your code here with something more in line with Android conventions. RecyclerView's are specifically designed to handle the case of a dynamic number of similar layouts. You can leverage a callback style interface in your RecyclerView.Adapter that bubbles up the id/position of the button tapped and from there you can select the data source to play, rather than setting the data source on each button, which may help disentangle some issues.

Comment: @Eli White, playEvent is just a method call that uses the data source to play the wav file in question. Apologies for not explaining that in the question